# DetailsView when DECODE data

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I have a DetailsView control that should display data from a DataBase. This data it is Encoded.

Which is the best way to DECODE this data before visualize the result in the DetailsView.

DataBound event handler? DataBinging Event Handler?

Could you give me an example of code.

Thanks for your time

Comment: You'll need to know the original encoding method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As IrishChieftain mentioned you need to know the method you used to encode the data. For code
I suggest having a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx